# Using tables for a blog design?

Tags: html, css, templates, css-tables

I'm learning CSS and HTML and for practice I'm trying to replicate w3schools templates while making all of the responsive as well. I found out this one that really caught me [template link](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_fashion_blog.htm). I've made it through until the end of front image, but I don't know how to do the post entries, is like a block but I inspected the element and has a `display: table;` on it and if you resize the browser you can that the row that was on the right is translated to the bottom of the page. Also, the element has a `float: left;` so that makes me think that the element are floating next to each other as soon as there's enough space for both of them. What do you  think?

Comment: If you just want a blogging website and are not really a programmer, I'd suggest just learning to install and use wordpress instead. CMS is more suitable for simple and consistent websites like a blog.

Comment: Actually I'm Computer Engineering student, just wanna learn CSS and HTML fundamentals without using frameworks, once I've learned enough I'll proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make responsive web pages I would look into using bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com). They have examples and the corresponding documentation explaining how to use it. You can either download bootstrap for use or use the CDNs provided on the site.

Comment: Actually I'm Computer Engineering student, just wanna learn CSS and HTML fundamentals without using frameworks, once I've learned enough I'll proceed.

Comment: Would it be possible to copy some of your current code into the question? Then we should be able to help you out with what you are trying to accomplish.